# PHPMailer() not sending mail

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm trying to implement a contact form on a website running PHP 8.1 with the latest `PHPMailer()` code but it won't send any mails. I don't know how to debug it remotely since the webserver doesn't allow `SSH` (I can debug it to some extent with xdebug on a localhost) and I got it to work with an older `PHPMailer()` library and the webserver running on PHP 7.4. All the error logging is turned on on the webserver `error_reporting` set to `-1` and `display_errors` to `1` and no errors are visible (not in the browser console, the error logs of the server or in the browser). `SMTP` can't be used in this case so it must send with `sendmail`. The site `contact.php` includes

```
require_once("contact/include/fgcontactform.php");
```

This is in `fgcontactform.php`

```
require_once("PHPMailer.php");
require_once("Exception.php");
//require_once("SMTP.php");

/*
Interface to Captcha handler
*/
class FG_CaptchaHandler
{
    function Validate() { return false;}
    function GetError(){ return '';}
}
/*
FGContactForm is a general purpose contact form class
It supports Captcha, HTML Emails, sending emails
conditionally, File atachments and more.
*/
class FGContactForm
{
    var $receipients;
    var $errors;
    var $error_message;
    var $name;
    var $email;
    var $message;
    var $from_address;
    var $form_random_key;
    var $conditional_field;
    var $arr_conditional_receipients;
    var $fileupload_fields;
    var $captcha_handler;

    var $mailer;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->receipients = array();
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->form_random_key = 'HTgsjhartag';
        $this->conditional_field='';
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients=array();
        $this->fileupload_fields=array();

        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    }
```

This is the form HTML in `contact.php`

```
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

This is the function in fgcontactform.php

```
    function GetSelfScript()
    {
        return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
```

When I click on `SEND MESSAGE` on the contact form it should redirect to some external website which works with the old `PHPMailer()` but not with the new one in `contact.php`

```
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
       $formproc->RedirectToURL("https://www.google.com/");
   }
}
```

This is the POST request from the Firefox Dev console

```
-----------------------------12990316242892709467429570469
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submitted"

1
-----------------------------12990316242892709467429570469
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id8d10e0a2c32d37a59eed"

b433f008dc4d6209e071b3b3a2b8459a
-----------------------------12990316242892709467429570469
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="spc1b79d21e61baf3fd8e15f01ff9b5c80"


-----------------------------12990316242892709467429570469
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

test
-----------------------------12990316242892709467429570469
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

test@test.com
-----------------------------12990316242892709467429570469
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

test
-----------------------------12990316242892709467429570469
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload1"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------12990316242892709467429570469
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload2"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------12990316242892709467429570469
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="scaptcha"

VAGEHL
-----------------------------12990316242892709467429570469--
```

Update 1:
This should send the message

```
    function SendFormSubmission()
    {
        $this->CollectConditionalReceipients();

        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
        
        $this->mailer->Subject = "Kontaktaufnahme von $this->name";

        $this->mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

        $this->mailer->FromName = $this->name;

        $this->mailer->AddReplyTo($this->email);

        $message = $this->ComposeFormtoEmail();

        $textMsg = trim(strip_tags(preg_replace('/<(head|title|style|script)[^>]*>.*?<\/\\1>/s','',$message)));
        $this->mailer->AltBody = @html_entity_decode($textMsg,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
        $this->mailer->MsgHTML($message);

        $this->AttachFiles();

        if(!$this->mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->add_error("Fehler beim Senden der Nachricht!");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I've also swapped `var` with `public`

---

The reply is `contact.php` although that should redirect me to `google.com`.
Can anyone help me debug this problem or give hints as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You haven't shared any code that sends the message

Comment: If your class is still using `var` to define properties, it to is a bit on the ancient side

Comment: The code you've shared does not call `SendFormSubmission` after all - could this be a reason for not sending any mail after all?

Comment: https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/ has a simple guide to debugging with PHP. For example, have you verified that `->Send()` is ever actually being executed? As per the comments above, it seems like it might not be.